# How to insert rows and cells for missing time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]

As seen from the photo, there are minutes missing. How would I make it so that I can fill in the missing time, and the value in column B would just = NA?

Answer (score 0):

I would love to help you but I will need some more information about the problem you are having.

Can you elaborate on the question a little more? What are you trying to accomplish with this?